# Установить значение кнопки-переключателя

Tags: java, android, android-switch

У меня в меню есть кнопка-переключатель
При ее изменении меняется иконка и в `SharedPreferences` пишется значение `0` или `1`
Проблема в том, что при старте активности эта кнопка всегда выкл. Как мне из `SharedPreferences` подтянуть значение и задать ввиду этого для `boolean birthSort` `false` или `true`?

```
boolean birthSort=false;
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.menu_toogle:

                Intent position = getIntent();
                int positionValue = position.getIntExtra("head", 0);
                SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences("MyAppFavorites", MODE_PRIVATE);
                SharedPreferences.Editor value_add = settings.edit();


                if(birthSort){
                    item.setIcon(R.drawable.toggle_off);
                    birthSort=false;
                    value_add.putFloat(String.valueOf(positionValue), 0);
                    value_add.commit();
                    Toast.makeText(this, R.string.fav_del, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
                else{
                    item.setIcon(R.drawable.toggle_on);
                    birthSort=true;
                    value_add.putFloat(String.valueOf(positionValue), 1);
                    value_add.commit();
                    Toast.makeText(this, R.string.fav_add, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
                return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

После создания меню в методе `onCreateOptionsMenu` выставляем положение переключателя, значение из префов берём здесь же или в `onCreate` записываем в поле.
Поскольку положений всего два, то удобнее использовать `boolean` (если будет больше - `int`, `float` - для таких целей не стоит), но имейте в виду, что читать и писать нужно одним типом (`putBoolean()/getBoolean()`), иначе правильное значение не получите:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // создание меню, стандартный пример (здесь должен быть ваш код)
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.game_menu, menu);

    // получаем значения настроек
    Intent position = getIntent();
    int positionValue = position.getIntExtra("head", 0);

    SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences("MyAppFavorites", MODE_PRIVATE);
    birthSort = settings.getBoolean(String.valueOf(positionValue), false);

    // находим элементы и настраиваем их
    Item item = menu.findItem(R.id.menu_toogle);
    if (birthSort) {
        item.setIcon(R.drawable.toggle_on);
    } else {
        item.setIcon(R.drawable.toggle_off);
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Спасибо, код работает с небольшой оговоркой, которая взрывает мне мозг: если `positionValue` равно 0, 1, 2, 5, 7, 25 то приложение падает с ошибкой https://www.dropbox.com/s/ti594td0qkwfgcp/IMG_20191229_122640.jpg?dl=0 Если `positionValue` равно 3,4, 6, 8-24, 26-42 то все работает

Comment: По данным позициям у вас уже были записаны `float`-значения, из-за этого падает. Очистите данные приложения или удалите конкретно этот преференс-файл через Device File Explorer в студии.

Comment: Очистил, пробовал и на реальном устройстве, не помогает ни чистка приложения, ни его переустановка

Comment: вы, безусловно, правы, просто меня волнует, как пройдет обновление и не будут ли крашиться приложения у моих пользователей?

Comment: Сделал проще - MyAppFavorites переименовал в MyFavorites, все работает. Ваш код немного видоизменил (в таком виде он не работал), но направление мысли вы мне задали верное)

Comment: Я не вижу весь ваш код, поэтому не могу что-то пояснить. Если в прошлой версии, которая у юзеров, не было этих записей, то обновление ничего не сломает. Если были, то можно по-вашему (сменить имя) и забить на старые записи (не думаю, что они у вас занимают много места). Можно конечно и подчистить, подписав ресивер на `android.intent.action.MY_PACKAGE_REPLACED` и в нём удалить ненужное. Если в моём коде что-то не верно - вы можете исправить ответ или опубликовать свой.

Comment: @ru38irk, ваша правка не может быть верной - так не используется значение из преференсов, а присваивается прямо в условии сначала false, потом true и в итоге у вас всегда при запуске будет иконка `toggle_on`. Перепроверьте! Думаю понял, в чём проблема - я скопировал условие из вашего кода, а здесь нужно обратное (поправил).

Comment: Так работает, и мой вариант тоже работает

Comment: Но ваш код лучше. лаконичнее )) Спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

Для получения данного значения нужно прописать такой код в методе `onCreate()`:

```
SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences("MyAppFavorites", 0);
int value= settings.getInt("your_pref_name", 0); //0 по-умолчанию
```

Я бы советовал эти строки указать до построения вью перед setContentView() но можно и после. Я где-то читал что можно как если перед построением то при построении уже все будет подтянуто. Дальше у вас есть глобальная переменная birthSort, которая будет меняться в зависимости от полученного значения из памяти, что-то типа такого:

```
switch (value) {
           case  (0):
               // будет false
               break;
           case (1):
                // будет true
               break;

       }
```

и дальше уже в слушателе меню обработку значений.